# Python Read chunks of complete rows from large text file (column values split across multiple rows)

Tags: python, text-files

I want to read a large .txt file (c.2.5GB) in chunks and then perform some operations before loading into the database.

The file only has 2 columns (column delimiter is `¬`) and is qualified with `double quotes`. The values in the second column could span across multiple lines (sample below). I thought of using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python/519653#519653) but the issue would be that it might process incomplete lines as it depends on preset `chunk size`. Can someone please help? I've included the sample data and code below.

**Sample Data (Sample_load_file.txt)**

```
"LINE_ID"¬"LINE_TEXT"
"C1111-G00-BC222"¬"this line is
split into
multiple lines
% All needs to be read into 1 line
% Currently that's not happening
"
"C22-f0-333"¬"2nd row. This line is
split into
multiple lines
% All needs to be read into 1 line
% Currently that's not happening
  *******************************************************************
  This line also includes the column delimiter within text qualifier
  *******************************************************************
  # !¬!¬!¬|
"
```

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from dbconnection import DBConnection

path = r'C:\Sample_load_file.txt'
db = DBConnection(server ='XXXX', database='XXXX')

def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=1024):
    #Lazy load to read a file piece by piece (avoiding moemory issues)
    #Default chunk size: 1k.
    while True:
        data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data
        
def process_chunk(data=piece):
    #Build a list of lines based on ' "\n" ' as custom separator
    data = data.split('"\n"')
    
    #Split each line based on ' "¬" ' as custom separator
    data = [line.split('"¬"') for line in data]
    
    #Cleanup remaining double quotes
    data = [[e.replace('"', '') for e in line] for line in data]
    
    #Check the number of columns
    number_of_cols = len(str(data[0]).split('¬'))
    number_of_cols
    
    #Load data into a dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    #Reformat dataframe
    df.columns = df.iloc[0] # Set first row as column index
    df = df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True) # Drop first line and reset index
    
    #Split the first column into two
    try:
        df[['LINE_ID', 'LINE_TEXT']] = df['LINE_IDÂ¬LINE_TEXT'].str.split('¬',expand=True)
    except:
        print('Error')
    del df['LINE_IDÂ¬LINE_TEXT']
    
    #Add metadata
    df['loaded_by'] = 'XXXX'
    df['file_line_number'] = range(2,len(df)+2)
    df['load_date'] = pd.datetime.now()
    df['source_file'] = path
    df['loading_script'] = r'Load_Extracts.ipynb'    
    
    #Load in SQL db
    df.to_sql('SQL_table_name', db.engine, schema='dbo', index=False, if_exists='append')
    
#Load text file
with open(path) as f:
    for piece in read_in_chunks(f):
        process_data(piece)
```

Comment: Do `LINE_ID` values also span multiple lines, or can one assume that they always fit in one line? Also is there any particular reason to read the file in chunks of characters or lines, or reading it line by line would also work?

Comment: @NikolaosChatzis no. The `LINE_ID` always fits on one line. On your 2nd question - No prob in reading line by line, but the issue is to understand how many lines would make up one "row" of data since that's not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If `LINE_ID` fits in one line you could try using a generator that leverages that the first line of a multiline record contains `"¬"`:

```py
def make_records(file):
    current = []
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if '"¬"' in line:
            if current:
                yield " ".join(current)
            current = [line]
        else:
            current.append(line)
    yield " ".join(current)
```

With the example input:

```py
>>> import io
>>> 
>>> s = '''"LINE_ID"¬"LINE_TEXT"
... "C1111-G00-BC222"¬"this line is
... split into
... multiple lines
... % All needs to be read into 1 line
... % Currently that's not happening
... "
... "C22-f0-333"¬"2nd row. This line is
... split into
... multiple lines
... % All needs to be read into 1 line
... % Currently that's not happening
...   *******************************************************************
...   This line also includes the column delimiter within text qualifier
...   *******************************************************************
...   # !¬!¬!¬|
... "'''
>>> f = io.StringIO(s)
>>> for record in make_records(f):
...    print(record)
... 
"LINE_ID"¬"LINE_TEXT"
"C1111-G00-BC222"¬"this line is split into multiple lines % All needs to be read into 1 line % Currently that's not happening "
"C22-f0-333"¬"2nd row. This line is split into multiple lines % All needs to be read into 1 line % Currently that's not happening   *******************************************************************   This line also includes the column delimiter within text qualifier   *******************************************************************   # !¬!¬!¬| "
```

Notes: You may want  to change what the generator `yield`s, e.g., `list` or `tuple` instead of `str`, remove double quotes, skip the first row, based on your needs. I used `io.StringIO` for illustration purposes only, you will read from a "normal" file.